# react multiform async onsubmit called multiple times

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a react app that contains a multistep form that looks like:

```js
 <React.Fragment>
     <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
         <Modal.Header closeButton>
             <Modal.Title>Step {this.state.currentStep}: {this._title}</Modal.Title>
         </Modal.Header>
         <Modal.Body>
             {this._step1}
             {this._step2}
         </Modal.Body>
         <Modal.Footer>
             {this._footerButtons}
         </Modal.Footer>
    </form>
 </React.Fragment>
```

where `_step1` and `_step2` are just a list of input tags, and the footer buttons look like:

```js
get _footerButtons() {
    if (this.state.currentStep == 1) {
        return (
            <>
                <Button className="modal-button-secondary" onClick={this.props.close}>
                    Cancel
                </Button>
                <Button className="modal-button-primary" onClick={this._nextStep}>
                    Continue
                </Button>
            </>
        )
    } else if (this.state.currentStep == 2) {
        return (
            <>
                <Button className="modal-button-secondary" onClick={this._prevStep}>
                    Back
                </Button>
                <Button type="submit" className="modal-button-primary">Create</Button>
            </>
        )
    }
    return null;
}
```

and `handleSubmit` looks at a high level like:

```js
async handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    let data = {
        ....
    }
    let result = await fetch(
        'http://localhost:8080/',
        {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify(data),
            mode: 'no-cors'
        }
    )
    console.log(result)
}
```

but what ends up happening, when transitioning from step 1 to step 2, submit form makes a request by calling `handleSubmit` and then also when the `create` button is called in step 2.

EDIT:
`this._nextStep` looks like the following:

```js
 _nextStep() {
    let currentStep = this.state.currentStep
    currentStep = currentStep + 1
    this.setState({
        currentStep: currentStep
    })
}
```

Comment: You might wanna add `type="button"` in cancel and continue button.

Comment: @Piyush thanks for responding, I tried that, but it did not help.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `ref` for form and when button for step_2 clicked use that ref for explicitly handle submission of form.

**Note:** If this not works then please post your code of `this._nextStep`

Comment: I added the `this._nextStep` to the original question, I am trying to get your suggestion to work still however

Comment: Your `_nextStep` code looks fine to me. Any luck with `ref` BTW.

Comment: If you still stuck with this problem then I think you should go for using `ref`. I'm preferring this solution because it provides you the control to submit form when certain condition matched.
Note: Don't forget to remove type="submit" from submit button if you are using `ref`.

Comment: the ref didn't work, I ended up with keeping state of if it's time to submit by using the final button to update the state to `true` and then the `handleSubmit` only exists on when the state is submitting

Comment: Ok that can be useful too